# Child and grandchild taxonomy listings - 404

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have the following structure:

- Hotels (custom post type)
- Continents (taxonomy)

Working actual links examples leading to single post:
*hotels/europe/france/a-hotel*
*hotels/europe/italy/firenze/a-hotel*

Problem: getting 404 when trying to access childs and grandchilds listings:

- *hotel/europe* - **works!**
- *hotel/europe/france* - **404**
- *hotel/europe/france/paris* - **404**

Not sure if something is missing, should I use a page template for those access points?

The code was hard to get working, thanks for examples around here:
http://pastebin.com/WYJLYjHM

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding a filter and building the permalink. FIrt forget the pastebin code, just create a post type a nd the taxos you want, them add the filter:

```
add_filter('post_link', 'territorio_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'territorio_permalink', 10, 3);

function territorio_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
if (strpos($permalink, '%territorio%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

// Get post
$post = get_post($post_id);
if (!$post) return $permalink;

// Get taxonomy terms
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'territorio');
if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0]))
$taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug.'/'.$terms[1]->slug; //build here
else $taxonomy_slug = 'not-yet';

return str_replace('%territorio%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

In post type creation use:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'anything-you-want/%territorio%','with_front' => false),
```

Note: if you want deeper links, your build should go deeper:

```
$taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug.'/'.$terms[1]->slug.'/'.$terms[2]->slug;
```